# How to tag resources created under a certain k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, billing

How to tag resources created under a certain k8s cluster, we have multiple teams which create cluster and the corresponding pods, in order to understand the costing corresponding to it we would like to tag the resources so that we know how much a team is spending. We use standard yaml files for k8s deployment in GKE. How should we go about doing this, to understanding the billing associated with usage

Comment: Did you read [this section](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports) of GCP docs ? You can select specific service for example, Compute Engine or Cloud Storage to view their respective cost. _"we have multiple teams which create cluster and the corresponding pods"_ - as already mentioned by Jonas, you're not charged for the workload you deploy on your GKE cluster but for the underlying infrastructure, so basically you rather need to track the cost of Compute Engine VMs or [networking resources](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing) used by your cluster rather than Pods.

Answer (score 0):

> resources created under a certain k8s cluster

Resources *under* the cluster, e.g. nodes are created outside the cluster, using e.g. Terraform or other tools - these tools typically has features to add tags for tracking costs.

> We use standard yaml files for k8s deployment in GKE.

This is resources created within the cluster, those are not typically tracked by the cloud provider, since you only pay for the underlying infrastructure e.g. nodes and network traffic.

So to track this in a more granular way, you typically has to install an add-on like e.g. [kubecost](https://kubecost.com/), so that you can see e.g. how big part of your costs is consumed by "team A".